# How can I get the data attribute from a php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form that can delete records from a MySql database using ajax and jQuery. I'm trying to get the jQuery to only select the relevant record passed to it and not just delete the top row of records which it does at the moment. I think I need to get

```
<div class="'.$id.'">
```

from my form and make it a data attribute that can be selected. Hope I'm making myself clear. Many thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Delete Review
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Need to get $id here.
        $(".deleteReview").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var film_id = $("#film_id").val();
            var id = $("#id").val();

            $.post('ajax_deleteReview.php', {
                username: username,     
                film_id: film_id, 
                id: id
            }, function(data) {
                $("#message").html(data);
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
                $("#message").fadeOut(2500); 
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="'.$id.'">
        <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="'. $username.'">
        <input type="hidden" id="film_id" name="film_id" value="'.$film_id .'">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="'.$id .'">
        <button type="submit" id="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">delete</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `deleteReview` element? Wild guess, you need  `$(this).closest('div').attr('class')`

Comment: <div class ="'.$id.'"> was the deleteReview element.

Comment: why not give `<div id ="<?php $id; ?>"`?

Comment: `$(".deleteReview").` will never fire with this code. @Dray That would be invalid if `$id` is an integer; `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: oh! i totally forgot! thanks buddy. @chris85

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed attributes to persists your data.

*HTML*

```
 <div data-id="'.$id.'" data-username="'. $username.'" data-filmid="'.$film_id .'" class="deleteReview">
    <button type="submit" id="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">delete</button>
 <div >
```

Then you can fetch it using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-* attribute

*Script*

```
 //Delete Review
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Need to get $id here.
    $(".deleteReview").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $(this).data("username");
        var film_id = $(this).data('filmid');
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        ......
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First in your PHP do something like this, you add the data attributes to your delete button since you are not actually submitting a real form.  I also moved the deleteReview class to the button.

```
print '<button type="submit" class="deleteReview" data-id="'.$id.'" data-film-id="'.$film_id.'" data-username="'.htmlentities($username).'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">delete</button>';
```

Then, in your jQuery, update click event callback like so:

```
$(".deleteReview").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username=$(this).data('username');
    var film_id=$(this).data("film-id");
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    /* the rest of your code */
```

The data attributes become accessible easily with jQuery using `$(this).data('some-attribute-name')`