# How to get data attribute value?

Tags: php

I have a url within a data-attribute and I need to get the first one:

```
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)"; class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="http://esportareinsvizzera.com/site/wp-content/uploads/8.jpg">
</div>
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="http://www.finanziamentiprestitimutui.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/esportazioni-finanziamento-credito.jpg">
</div>
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);"  class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="http://www.infologis.biz/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Export.jpg">
</div>
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);"  class="carousel-cell-image"  data-flickity-lazyload="http://www.cigarettespedia.com/images/2/25/Esportazione_horizontal_name_ks_20_s_green_italy.jpg">
</div>
```

I have been reading lots of answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511081/how-can-i-get-the-data-attribute-from-a-php-variable) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286184/access-html-5-data-attribute-in-php) but I am not a php guy.

I was using this to get the first img but now I need the actual data attribute value instead

```
<?php
      $custom_image = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-4');
      $custom_image = htmlspecialchars_decode($custom_image);
      $custom_image = nl2br($custom_image);
      $custom_image = preg_replace('/<br \/>/iU', '', $custom_image);
      preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i',$custom_image, $image);
    ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $image['src']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML, get the elements corresponding to `img` tags and get the `data-flickity-lazyload` attribute of the first  `img` tag:

```
...
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($custom_image);
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');

$mySrc = $items->item(0)->getAttribute('data-flickity-lazyload');
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot, shall i do this then? $mySrc = $items[0]->getAttribute('data-flickity-lazyload'); <img src="<?php echo $mySrc; ?> ? Because it doesn't work..

Comment: Provide more info on your error: do you see any warning message? what is the content of `$mySrc`? What is the content of `$custom_image` when you load it to the `DOMDocument`?

Comment: if I do echo $custom_image i get `<div class="carousel-cell">
  <img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="http://esportareinsvizzera.com/site/wp-content/uploads/8.jpg">
 </div>`

Comment: Maybe it's an encoding issue. Could you post the output of `var_dump($mySrc)`?

Comment: This whole code is within a post i get call with ajax, so i don't even get a var_dump, it simply breaks it

Comment: I updated my answer. Copy and paste that piece of code (I know the quotes look empty, but they are not)